# Generate random Salt using securerandom

Tags: random, byte, salt

I want to generate a random salt...

I am doing this but get the same salt every time even if I restart my program .. i checked using println

```
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNGBlocking");

    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    System.out.println(salt);

    return salt;
```

How to generate a random salt? I want a separate salt for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes in the salt array will in fact be different, at least unless the NativePRNGBlocking implementation is broken. I think the problem is in your check. The toString method for byte arrays does not print the values in the array, so printing the salt array in that way is useless. Try to print the individual values:

```
for(byte b: salt) { 
 System.out.print(b + " "); 
}
```

Or you could just inspect them in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

SecureRandom class supports the “SHA1PRNG” pseudo random number generator algorithm.

Try the below code it works fine for me and getting always unique outptut.

```
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
//Create array for salt
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
//Get a random salt
sr.nextBytes(salt);
//return salt
System.out.println( salt.toString());
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.